# R is taking ages to cluster documents, what other options do I have?

Tags: r, clustering

I was trying k-medoids algorithm for clustering in R, and just removing stopwords is taking hours. After I removed stopwords, I let the algorithm run overnight and it wasn't done after 8-9 hours. I am trying to cluster 40.000 documents, what alternatives do I have? Should I wait it out? I am just afraid that it will never stop, the application will just stop responding. Is it normal for the script to take 10+ hours to run?

This is my code:

```
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(userbios$bio))
    docs <- userbios$twitter_id
# convert to lower case
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, tolower)
# remove punctuation
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
# remove numbers
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
# remove URLs
removeURL <- function(x) gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*", "", x)
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeURL)
# add extra stop words
myStopwords <- c("twitter", "tweets", "tweet", "tweeting", "account")
summary(myStopwords)

# remove stopwords from corpus
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, myStopwords)

# keep a copy of corpus to use later as a dictionary for stem completion
myCorpusCopy <- myCorpus
# stem words
# require(rJava) # needed for stemming function 
# library(Snowball) # also needed for stemming function 
# a <- tm_map(myCorpus, stemDocument, language = "english")

myTdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(wordLengths=c(1,Inf), weighting=weightTf))
myTdm2 <- removeSparseTerms(myTdm, sparse=0.85)
m2 <- as.matrix(myTdm2)
m3 <- t(m2)

library(fpc)
pamResult <- pamk(m3, metric="manhattan")
k<-pamResult$nc
    pamResult <- pamResult$pamobject

 # print cluster medoids
 for (i in 1:k) {
 cat(paste("cluster", i, ": "))
 cat(colnames(pamResult$medoids)[which(pamResult$medoids[i,]==1)], "\n")
 # print tweets in cluster i
  print(docs[pamResult$clustering==i])
 }
```

Comment: A reasonable approach to such a problem would to run with a number of randomly selected subsets of the 40,000 documents of known and increasing sizes that run fairly quickly (e.g. 50 documents, 100 documents, 500 documents, 1000 documents, etc...).  Given this information you should at least have an approximate estimate for the expected amount of time the problem should take (e.g. fit a set of polynomials to the observed runtimes and extrapolate to 40,000 documents).

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code? The crudest way would be to output `Sys.time()` after every statement, along with some diagnostic info. Then you would at least know how far you have come and how long every step took. (I also frequently have scripts that run long, I also like `winProgressBar()`, but I guess that is not helpful for your problem).

Comment: I am using R64, which tells me which step is being carried out as it is being compiled. Would sys.time() do more than that?

Comment: If I recall correctly, PAM is known to be quite slow. You may want to limit the number of iterations it does. Furthermore, you can try to *start with a subset only*, then add more objects and continue the algorithm from the earlier solution. Not sure if R allows that, though.